# How to disable stackview autosize

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uistackview

So I have three text fields inside a horizontal stackview that are like this:

[image: This]

I've made this by **placing a placeholder text** and selected **Fill Porportionally** from the Stack View menu.

However, I would really love to stick with this ratio but everytime I type something long, the text fields increase automatically. Is there anyway to disable auto sizing so that I can keep these initial ratio at all times?

*Note: second and third text fields are **not** the same size*

Thanks!!

Edit: Bump.. ='(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add width constraints to the views, setting them to the widths you want. Or set constraints between the views to control their proportions directly.

Your view widths seem to be 272, 135, and 168. So create an equal-width constraint between the left and middle views, then edit the constraint to set its multiplier to 272:135. Then create an equal-width constraint between the left and the right views and set its multiplier to 272:168.